# How to login to multiple account at same time with Microsoft WebView2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview2

I have create an application with a webview2 control and run it and do login with user A to my website, then run my application again without closing the previous instance and do login with user B on same website, then the login is successful. And when I check the previous instance, the user A is still logged in. How to do the same way but on one instance application? I have tried it with two webview2 control and when I do login with user B, the user A is logged out or the session is replaced with user B.

Comment: since logons are controlled with cookies, you probably just have to switch out cookies for different users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebVeiw2 uses [user data folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/userdatafolder?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to store the cookies.

To start another instance of the control in a different session, as an option, you can set [UserDataFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.corewebview2creationproperties.userdatafolder?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_WinForms_CoreWebView2CreationProperties_UserDataFolder), for example:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView21.CreationProperties =
        new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties();
    webView21.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        Application.StartupPath, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}");
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://outlook.com");
}
```

For those who want to start using [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2?&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), you need to have [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [Microsoft Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) installed on your machine. You also need to install [WebView2 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in your project. Then you can start here: [Getting started with WebView2 in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: It works! thank you!.... NOTE: if we add the webview2 control to form with the designer, I have to add the webView21.CreationProperties and webView21.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder inside the initializecontrol() function at the form new() and put it (at beginning) BEFORE set any other webview2 properties like webview2.Dock,  webview2.Location etc. (or move the webview2 property setting after the initializeControl call on form new()) If not, I got an InvalidOperationException

Comment: I also used designer for my controls, and put the code in `button1_Click` event hadndler and it worked well.

Comment: I will check it again, maybe something's wrong with my code...

Comment: Yes, you're right! There's problem with my code...  I create new form and test your code and it works...

Comment: Cool, thanks for verifying that. Let me know if you had any related finding on that :)

Comment: Note that this will create a new userdata folder each time you run your program, this will not be automatically deleted again.

Comment: @PoulBak Thanks for highlighting, since we set the path ourselves, then I assume it's obvious for the readers to take care of the path and keeping or removing it. I also assume the readers will read the first link in the answer as well.

Comment: I have the same issue, and i agree with  PoulBak. This solution works but the memory keep goring ... one day your drive will explode

Comment: @Zimo You should take care of that based on your requirement. For example you can treat it like incognito mode and delete the folder when you close the application.