How to login to multiple account at the same time with Microsoft WebView2 in UWP C#
My UWP app has multiple instances of webview2 control. How to allow different login from webview2 instances.
What i have observed is if we login in the first webview2 control , then go and refresh the second webview2 control it uses the login of the
first control. I guess it has to do with Userdata folder
How to control this behavior for the below  scenarios and how to set custom userdata folder in UWP C#?

option with multiple login credentials.
option with shared login credentials.


Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849338/how-to-login-to-multiple-account-at-same-time-with-microsoft-webview2

@JunjieZhu-MSFT , that is for the winforms. In UWP C# we don't have CreationProperties .

@JunjieZhu-MSFT , that is for the winforms. In UWP C# we don't have CreationProperties . Also can get the userdatafolder , but cant set the userdatafolder as it is readonly. WebView2.CoreWebView2.Environment.UserDataFolder.

The UWP version of webview2 doesn't have this API, it looks like it's by design, I suggest you ask in the webview2 GitHub issue. https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues
